# How to use this Hyphenation library in delphi?

Tags: delphi, hyphenation

This is a hyphenation lib by [Synopse delphi open source](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=74).

The demo is a console application. I do not know how to use it in GUI application.

Below is my test, but not work. It does not display word with hyphen (or separaror). The lib can be [downloaded here:](http://synopse.info/files/hyphen.zip)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, hyphen, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure testhyphenator;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.testhyphenator;
var
  h: THyphen;
  s: string;
  F, L: Integer;
begin
  s := 'hyph_en_US.txt'; //this is from the folder, is that correct to call?
  if FileExists(s) then 
  begin
    F := FileOpen(s, fmOpenRead);
    L := FileSeek(F, 0, soFromEnd);
    if L > 0 then 
    begin
      SetLength(s, L);
      FileSeek(F, 0, soFromBeginning);
      FileRead(F, s[1], L);    
    end;
    FileClose(F);
  end;
  h := THyphen.Create(s);
  h.Execute('pronunciation'); //is this correct?
  ShowMessage(h.filllist); //not display hyphenated word
end;
```

It does not display hyphenated word. In the demo, I am also confused about the constructor:

```
H := THyphen.create('ISO8859-1'#10'f1f'#10'if3fa/ff=f,2,2'#10'tenerif5fa');
 writeln('"',H.Execute('SchiffahrT'),'"'); writeln(H.FillList);
 ...
```

The author has also enclosed the obj file. If I want to compile it into a single exe, how to do it?

Can you please help me understand how to use it correctly?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? *Doesn't work* is the worst description of a problem you can use. And to your question *how to link the *.obj file* use `{$LINK 'file.obj'}` in your unit.

Comment: @TLama, Thanks for reply. Please see edit. I mean it does not display hyphenated word.

Comment: 1) Did you succeed compiling the original console app version on your box? 2) What's your Delphi version?

Comment: Why don't you post your question on the Synopse forum:  http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=74  I'm sure the author of the program, Arnaud Bouchez, will answer you there (if he doesn't answer you here first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: I have harnessed a not so recent distribution of Hyphen, it may not be in sync with the [latest version](http://synopse.info/files/hyphen.zip).

Here are my points:

Compilation of the distribution

- I have compiled it under Delphi 7 and it's **OK**.

hyphen.rc File

- There is no **hyph_en_EN.dic** file in the distribution. If you are going to rebuild hyphen.res, you may need to fix **hyphen.rc** using the following:

hyphen Text HYPH_EN_US.dic

- I have not checked the `hyphen.res` file in the distribution wether it contains `hyph_en_EN.dic` and/or `hyph_en_US.dic`.

*.dic Files available in my distribution

- hyph_it_IT.dic
- hyph_es_ES.dic
- hyph_fr_FR.dic
- hyp_en_US.dic
- hyp_de_DE.dic

Answers to the comments in your snippet

```
s := 'hyph_en_US.txt'; //this is from the folder, is that correct to call?
```

No! The correct file extension is `.dic`. You should write instead:

```
s := 'hyph_en_US.dic;
```

The following is Ok (you can refer to the definition of THyphen class):

```
Execute('pronunciation'); // is this correct?
```

The following is Ok (but it doesn't work because `h` as a `THyphen` instance was not properly initialized):

```
ShowMessage(h.filllist); //not display hyphenated word
```

Your concern about the constructor

```
H := THyphen.create('ISO8859-1'#10'f1f'#10'if3fa/ff=f,2,2'#10'tenerif5fa');
```

It's just one of the proper way to set up `THyphen` (refer again to  the definition of `THyphen` class among others).

E.g.:

```
H := THyphen.create('EN');
```

Harnessing hyphen in a GUI App using Delphi 2007

- I can tell that it's OK so long as `THyphen` instance is properly constructed (Dont forget to include the `hyphen.res` resource file with `{$R hyphen.res}`, the `hyphen.obj` file is already linked in the `hyphen.pas` unit).

Last but not the least

- Feel free to get in touch with [Arnaud Bouchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458259/arnaud-bouchez) the great man behind [Synopse](http://synopse.info/). He is a Stackoverflow member and always ready to help for sure, a top [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) user moreover.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. I tested your code, now it is OK. The procedure generates possible break points as hyphens. 'pronunciation' generates pro=nun=ci=ation. Could it be used as syllable detect. If so, how can I modify that dic file to split 'ation' into  'a=tion', and finally have pro=nun=ci=a=tion? Or can you direct me to a resource for further study? Thank you very much again.

Comment: You are welcome. I must confess to you: I know nothing of hyphenation, I just delved into the source code and tried as much as I can do to solve your issues. I suggest you to post another post and tried to catch the attention of the hyphen's author I cited.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my Delphi install handy, so understand you may need to tweak this a bit.

After looking at the hyphen code, I believe you are using it incorrectly.  The parameter on the constructor is the language or character set.

```
h := THyphen.Create('UTF-8');
```

or (based on your file name, I think you need this next one)

```
h := THyphen.Create('EN');
```

Then "Execute" is used to generate a hyphenated version of the string passed in.  "Execute" is a function that returns a new string.  You are calling it, but not doing anything with the result.

```
NewStr := h.Execute('correct');
```

"NewStr" should now equal "cor-rect".

If I read the code correctly, the "FillList" function and procedure return a list of all of the possible hyphenation possibilities for the last word that was Execute'd.

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right, I am not using it correctly. I tested your code, The Filllist generates a list, each line indicating one separator. But I can not split accepted answer.

Comment: No problem.  Glad I could help.  It's more important that you get what you need than I get solution points.  Besides, menjaraz was able to compile and test for you.  ;)